# What is the Kelly Criterion for continuous probability case?

Tags: sharpe-ratio, kelly-criterion

Given return of a portfolio or a single asset modeled as a continuous, but not necessarily gaussian, probability distribution, what's the Kelly criterion equation?

I've heard that it's simply the the ratio of the sharpe ratio to the standard deviation. Is it true?

Comment: This was already discussed here http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/7199

Comment: This is discussed (among other places) in the book Investment Science by Luenberger

Comment: It is only true if there is a second moment in the distribution.  Given the data and papers on the topic, that claim would be very dubious.

Comment: The Sharpe Ratio is a rough but good approximation. In regard to approximating optimal bet size, the world of professional gambling is ahead of canonical portfolio managers. For a good essay on how this works, I recommend: https://wizardofodds.com/gambling/kelly-criterion/.